# Organize Views and ViewModels in Caliburn Framework

Tags: wpf, mvvm, view, viewmodel, caliburn

I would like to know what is the best way for organize View models in Caliburn MVVM framework.

I saw many samples in which view model was simple class located in folder with name ViewModels and views in folder Views.

For example, project has this structure:

```
- WPF app
  - ViewModels [Folder]
      -ShellViewModel [Class]
      -ViewModelA [Class]
      -ViewModelB [Class]
  -Views [Folder]
     -ShellView [Class]
     -ViewA [Class]
     -ViewB [Class]
```

In many situation I have realy complex view a view model.

In my opinion it will be good put view and view model in single WpfControlLibrary.

But I am not sure if this is good way for organize WPF app with MVVM design.

I think Caliburn framework will working also in situation when view model is not class in folder with name ViewModels.

So my question is what is correct and bets way for organize views and view models in WPF app which use Caliburn framework.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a new project the creator reccomends using Caliburn micro instead.  Either way it's fine to organize them in Views/ViewModels directory or to organize them by function like Customer.

In the hello screens example they're organized by function because each function is a module to be loaded.  Another good example of this is the [media owl](http://mediaowl.codeplex.com/) example where each module is in its own assembly.

The ViewModelLocator and ViewLocator can be configured to resolve ViewModels and views for many different structures.